# Integrating Facebook chat

Tags: javascript, facebook, chat

I was thinking of integrating facebook chat into my own site. Is there a JavaScript API for it? If so, can someone point me to a example/tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest you will get. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/

Comment: Thanks! but there is a field called "XID".. I'm not sure what i have to provide for the same. Any Idea??

Comment: According to the ? button next to the title "XID", it's in case you want multiple stream boxes on one page. So it's kinda like an id attribute for a normal div only it's specific to the fb widget so the messages go to the right box.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook has one chat api to integrate its xmpp based chat into Web-based, desktop, or mobile instant messaging products.

Here is the reference.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Answer (score 2):

Facebook chat is using XMPP.  You just need to write an XMPP client in javascript. There's even a book (reasonably good, I read it!): http://professionalxmpp.com/

Comment: Its lots and lots and lots of code to do this.  Including server side code.  Get the book.  Its worth it if this is something you're interested in.  Here's a jQuery plugin, but it requires an apache server to do the heavy lifting: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/xmpp (4th google hit for xmpp jquery by the way)